# Is this Event Mutally Exclusive?

Tags: probability, discrete-mathematics, dice

I am trying to calculate the following, however I'm unsure on whether this event would be Mutally Exclusive or Independent.

[image]
Can someone help with finding the probability of the Intersection?

P(A) = 7/20

P(B) = 1/2

P(A Intersection B) = ?
^ Would this simply be (7/20) * (1/2) ?

P(A Union B) = ?

P(B | A) = ?

Comment: $$\#(A\cap B)=\#\{14,16,18,20\}=4\quad\&\quad\#\Omega=20\quad\implies\qquad ??$$

Comment: @Did How did you get A Intersection B?

Comment: I tried to figure out the results greater than 13 **and** even.

Comment: By the way, your title seems quite inadequate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you actually write out the sets A and B, you can easily compute the intersection.

$$\Omega = \{1..20\}$$
$$A = \{14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20\}$$
$$B = \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 16, 18, 20\}$$
With this you get
$$A \cap B = \{14, 16, 18, 20\}$$
by simply looking at which elements are in both sets. Thus
$$ P(A \cap B) = \frac{|A \cap B|}{|\Omega|} = \frac{4}{20} $$
which is not the same as $$P(A)*P(B) = \frac{7}{20} * \frac{1}{2} = \frac{3.5}{20},$$ because A and B are not independent.

Likewise for the union you get
$$A \cup B = \{2, 4, 6, 8, 10, 12, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20\}.$$

Comment: `because` $\to$ `hence`.